# Delphi 7 persistent business object

Tags: delphi

Is there any way to make persistence of business objects with data from a database in Delphi 7?
Is it possible without using components.

Comment: The DORM framework is just out. You can take a look at this one, also. But I guess it won't work with Delphi 7... the source code is not yet available, but the concept is interesting.
http://www.delphifeeds.com/postings/71550-sneak_preview_about_dorm_the_delphi_orm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use our Open Source ORM framework, using SQLite3 database. Full RESTful framework, works locally (i.e. in process), or remotely via HTTP/1.1, Named pipes or GDI messages. No external dll required. Works with Delphi 7 up to 2010.

All is done without any component, directly from source code. All database SQL is created from  classes published properties.

For example, a People Table is defined in Delphi code as followed:

```
/// table used for the Babies queries
TSQLPeople = class(TSQLRecord)
  private
    fName: RawUTF8;
    fAddress: RawUTF8;
    fBirthDate: TDateTime;
  published
    property Name: RawUTF8 read fName write fName;
    property Address: RawUTF8 read fAddress write fAddress;
    property BirthDate: TDateTime read fBirthDate write fBirthDate;
end;
```

And you can access your data with code like this:

```
var People: TSQLPeople;
  ID: integer;
begin
  // create a new record, since Smith, Jr was just born
  People := TSQLPeople.Create;
  try
    People.Name := 'Smith';
    People.Address := 'New York City';
    People.BirthDate := Now;
    ID := Client.Add(People);
  finally
    People.Free;
  end;
  // retrieve record data
  People := TSQLPeople.Create(Client,ID);
  try
    assert(People.Name='Smith');
  finally
    People.Free;
  end;
end;
```

See http://blog.synopse.info/category/Open-Source-Projects/SQLite3-Framework

Answer (score 1):

hcOPF works with Delphi 7.  In fact it was developed with Delphi 7 and as a result does not use some of the newer language features.  Check it out on sourceforge.